# Script needed for Rest Client

Tags: rest, browser

I have got some 1000 URL's to be hit through a REST Client (like Dev Http Client)and store the response back .

Once hitting the 1000 Requests  , i need to grab the response of each request and store it some where .

Is this possible ??

I tried to use java API  for this with the help of HttpUrlConnection but 
i am getting security Exceptions . (Authentication problem)

(With Rest client i am not getting authentication issues , i already logged into that website so the cookies are set )

Please let me know if this is possible with any rest client ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Dev Http Client is using Oauth credentials provided by the browser (probably cookies?).
If you want to use Java you need to do some research on how to authenticate with the specific REST service you are trying to connect to. Basically it would come down to requesting an authorisation key and adding that to each HTTP request.
Or maybe you could try if in-browser javascript uses the browser credentials.